# USB Datacard not getting detected

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, 3g

I have a USB datacard which worked well with the backtrack5r3 (Which is based on Ubuntu 10.04LTS ) but it is not getting detected in Ubuntu 12.04LTS/13.04

The USB modem which I have been using will be first mounted as a CD-ROM with the drivers for  windows version and the dial up script for linux.

So to get connected to the internet I will eject/unmount the CDROM first and then dial up the connection.

The actual problem here is the CROM is not getting mounted.

I have tried getting connected to Internet using this method http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2028061 but it failed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After plugged in 3G data card modem, it is required to eject the data card to make Dial up or Mobile broadband connection to use  USB as USBtty device. But I found same problem as it stated above on 12.04LTS
I am using TERACOM 3G modem data card.

I found a temporary solution to eject the 3G modem and my Dial up and broadband working absolutely fine.

note : make sure your usb-modswitch package is installed.

1. launch Disk utility.-> 3G Modem Mass storage.
2. select -> Eject the data card. you will get error " device not detected" as expected.
3. Then select the CD/DVD Drive.
4. Select Again the 3G Modem Mass storage and Eject Again this time it will Eject the 3G Modem.
5. Then make Dial up or Mobile broadband connection this time it will connect successfully.

This is the Trick of Ejecting 3G Data card in between selecting CD/DVD drive